# Compute the distance between two elements in a ring

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ring-theory, computer-science

Given a ring of size $n = 2^m$, starting with element $0$ to element $n-1$, what general formula gives the distance between two arbitrary elements $i$ and $j$?
Note that the distance between the elements $0$ and $n-1$ is $1$.

There are a few cases...

- Assume for instance that $i>j$ and $|i-j|\leq\frac{n}{2}=2^{m-1}$, we
  then have $distance_{n}(i,j) = |i-j|$
- But for $\frac{n}{2} < |i-j| \leq n-1$, we need another formula. For e.g. let $n = 8$, then the distance between $1$ and $7$ is $1$, not $|7-1|=6$

What is the general, *one-line* formula for this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Would $\min ( |i-j|,n+1-|i-j|)$ work?

Comment: @coffemath Yes, this is what I needed. Actually it is $\min ( |i-j|,n-|i-j|)$. You added 1 because I incorrectly gave you the distance between 1 and 7 as 2 while it is 1; you took it into account. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**: $distance_{n}(i,j) = \min ( |i-j|,n-|i-j|)$